# Finding the probability of a random license plate.

Tags: probability

A standard license plate is made up of 3 letters and 4 numbers. Find the probability that a random license plate could be the following:
***YNG 2018***

*note: no letters or numbers can be repeated*

To complete this would I multiply 26 x 25 x 24 then add that to 10 x 9 x 8 x 7, since you have combinations of the numbers and letters. I also tried doing fractions, like 26/26, 25/25, but that gave me 1.

Comment: You should multiply your two products, not add them.

Comment: Do the letters in a "standard license plate" always appear in the first three spots like ABC1234?  Or might something like 1A2B3C4 be in a standard license plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability would be 1/26x25x24x10x9x8x7. Since they don't repeat you multiply by one less than the previous and since it is one specific combination. you would divide one by the all possible combinations. Hope it helps.